# How to run a test as standalone?

Tags: ruby, testunit

I want to organize multiple tests in the same file. And run them as single tests later.

Example:

`tests/TC_release1.rb` - the test file with like 10 tests in it
`ruby tests/TC_release1.rb --name test_TC_01` - to run a single test

Problem:

All the tests from the test file will be initialized (in my case 10 times). This is because of the "call order" described in the docs in http://test-unit.github.io/test-unit/en/Test/Unit/TestCase.html

Question:

How can I avoid that, and run it in stand-alone mode?

The test file

```
$ cat tests/TC_release1.rb
require 'rubygems'
require 'date'
require 'test/unit'

class TC_release1 < Test::Unit::TestCase
        def initialize(options)
                super
                puts DateTime.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")+" Hello from the init method."
        end

        def test_TC_01()
                puts DateTime.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")+" Start test 01"
                assert_match(/2017/, `date /T`)
                puts DateTime.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")+" End test 01"
        end
        def test_TC_02()
                assert_match(/2017/, `date /T`)
        end
        def test_TC_03()
                assert_match(/2017/, `date /T`)
        end
        def test_TC_04()
                assert_match(/2017/, `date /T`)
        end
        def test_TC_05()
                assert_match(/2017/, `date /T`)
        end
        def test_TC_06()
                assert_match(/2017/, `date /T`)
        end
        def test_TC_07()
                assert_match(/2017/, `date /T`)
        end
        def test_TC_08()
                assert_match(/2017/, `date /T`)
        end
        def test_TC_09()
                assert_match(/2017/, `date /T`)
        end
        def test_TC_10()
                assert_match(/2017/, `date /T`)
        end
end
```

Execute just the first test case from the test file

```
$ ruby tests/TC_release1.rb --name test_TC_01
2017-09-13T00:31:16 Hello from the init method.
2017-09-13T00:31:16 Hello from the init method.
2017-09-13T00:31:16 Hello from the init method.
2017-09-13T00:31:16 Hello from the init method.
2017-09-13T00:31:16 Hello from the init method.
2017-09-13T00:31:16 Hello from the init method.
2017-09-13T00:31:16 Hello from the init method.
2017-09-13T00:31:16 Hello from the init method.
2017-09-13T00:31:16 Hello from the init method.
2017-09-13T00:31:16 Hello from the init method.
Loaded suite tests/TC_release1
Started
2017-09-13T00:31:16 Start test 01
2017-09-13T00:31:16 End test 01
.

Finished in 0.048923 seconds.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

1 tests, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 pendings, 0 omissions, 0 notifications
100% passed
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

20.44 tests/s, 20.44 assertions/s
```

Comment: What do you mean "all the tests wil be initialized"? If you're doing a focused unit test that should only actually execute one of the tests.

Comment: you should not override the initializer. if you need to do setup, use a before/setup hook

Answer (score 0):

Ok, will be using `setup` hook as suggested by phoet.

Thanks.